# Firefox 38 on OS X - there is no DRM - howto enable?

Tags: macos, software, firefox, plugins, drm

I found [How to disable DRM in Firefox 38](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-drm-in-firefox-38/)

I don't have those settings in my Firefox. See screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Howto enable DRM restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you downloaded the DRM-free version of Firefox. You don't have the addon that provides the DRM in the first place.

Comment: Where would such version or add-on would be found?